# IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 Build #IU-201.6668.121 PsiAnnotationStubImpl Error

Tags: intellij-idea

After upgrading to the version in the title, i get the following exception and can't find out what's the problem. It seems like an annotation and parsing error inside of intellij.

To run the application i am using OpenJ9. Intellij itself runs with 11.0.6 like mentioned in the exception below.

```
2020-04-09 08:49:53,688 [1843359]  ERROR - ubs.impl.PsiAnnotationStubImpl - Bad annotation in jar:///home/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/jdk8/2.8.1/jdk8-2.8.1.jar!/java/util/List.class 
com.intellij.util.IncorrectOperationException: Incorrect annotation '@jdk.Profile+Annotation(value=1)'
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiJavaParserFacadeImpl.newException(PsiJavaParserFacadeImpl.java:389)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiJavaParserFacadeImpl.createAnnotationFromText(PsiJavaParserFacadeImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementFactoryImpl.createAnnotationFromText(PsiElementFactoryImpl.java:661)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.java.stubs.impl.PsiAnnotationStubImpl.getPsiElement(PsiAnnotationStubImpl.java:56)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsAnnotationImpl$2.compute(ClsAnnotationImpl.java:55)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsAnnotationImpl$2.compute(ClsAnnotationImpl.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.AtomicNotNullLazyValue.getValue(AtomicNotNullLazyValue.java:37)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsAnnotationImpl.getParameterList(ClsAnnotationImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsAnnotationImpl.appendMirrorText(ClsAnnotationImpl.java:65)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsElementImpl.appendText(ClsElementImpl.java:232)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsModifierListImpl.appendMirrorText(ClsModifierListImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsElementImpl.appendText(ClsElementImpl.java:224)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsClassImpl.appendMirrorText(ClsClassImpl.java:333)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsElementImpl.appendText(ClsElementImpl.java:224)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsFileImpl.appendMirrorText(ClsFileImpl.java:275)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsFileImpl.lambda$decompile$2(ClsFileImpl.java:545)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:864)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsFileImpl.decompile(ClsFileImpl.java:545)
    at jd.ide.intellij.JavaDecompilerService.decompile(JavaDecompilerService.java:58)
    at jd.ide.intellij.CachingJavaDecompilerService$2.load(CachingJavaDecompilerService.java:81)
    at jd.ide.intellij.CachingJavaDecompilerService$2.load(CachingJavaDecompilerService.java:77)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3936)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4806)
    at jd.ide.intellij.CachingJavaDecompilerService.accessToDecompiledText(CachingJavaDecompilerService.java:62)
    at jd.ide.intellij.CachingJavaDecompilerService.decompile(CachingJavaDecompilerService.java:53)
    at jd.ide.intellij.JavaLightClassDecompiler.getText(JavaLightClassDecompiler.java:22)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClassFileDecompiler.decompile(ClassFileDecompiler.java:26)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.LoadTextUtil.loadText(LoadTextUtil.java:470)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileDocumentManagerImpl.getDocument(FileDocumentManagerImpl.java:202)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsFileImpl.getMirror(ClsFileImpl.java:337)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsElementImpl.getMirror(ClsElementImpl.java:144)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.DebuggerUtilsImpl.getPsiClassAndType(DebuggerUtilsImpl.java:145)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.tree.render.CachedEvaluator.initEvaluatorAndChildrenExpression(CachedEvaluator.java:50)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.tree.render.CachedEvaluator.lambda$getEvaluator$1(CachedEvaluator.java:89)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.lambda$commitAndRunReadAction$6(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:524)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.lambda$commitAndRunReadAction$7(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:61)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.commitAndRunReadAction(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:547)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.commitAndRunReadAction(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:524)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.tree.render.CachedEvaluator.getEvaluator(CachedEvaluator.java:89)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.tree.render.ExpressionChildrenRenderer.isExpandable(ExpressionChildrenRenderer.java:156)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.tree.render.CompoundNodeRenderer.isExpandable(CompoundNodeRenderer.java:74)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.impl.watch.ValueDescriptorImpl.calcRepresentation(ValueDescriptorImpl.java:293)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.impl.watch.NodeDescriptorImpl.updateRepresentationNoNotify(NodeDescriptorImpl.java:69)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.impl.watch.NodeDescriptorImpl.updateRepresentation(NodeDescriptorImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.JavaValue$1.contextAction(JavaValue.java:178)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.events.SuspendContextCommandImpl.action(SuspendContextCommandImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.events.DebuggerCommandImpl.run(DebuggerCommandImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.DebuggerManagerThreadImpl.processEvent(DebuggerManagerThreadImpl.java:151)
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.DebuggerManagerThreadImpl.processEvent(DebuggerManagerThreadImpl.java:29)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.InvokeThread.lambda$run$0(InvokeThread.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runWithAlternativeResolveEnabled(DumbService.java:376)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.InvokeThread.run(InvokeThread.java:125)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.InvokeThread.access$100(InvokeThread.java:19)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.InvokeThread$WorkerThreadRequest.lambda$run$0(InvokeThread.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:210)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.InvokeThread$WorkerThreadRequest.run(InvokeThread.java:48)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected token: '+'
    at com.intellij.lang.java.parser.JavaParserUtil.parseFragment(JavaParserUtil.java:193)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.JavaElementType$JavaDummyElementType.parseContents(JavaElementType.java:263)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.LazyParseableElement.lambda$ensureParsed$0(LazyParseableElement.java:192)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DebugUtil.performPsiModification(DebugUtil.java:565)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.LazyParseableElement.ensureParsed(LazyParseableElement.java:191)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.LazyParseableElement.getFirstChildNode(LazyParseableElement.java:242)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.JavaDummyElement.getFirstChildNode(JavaDummyElement.java:69)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiJavaParserFacadeImpl.createAnnotationFromText(PsiJavaParserFacadeImpl.java:101)

2020-04-09 08:49:53,690 [1843361]  ERROR - ubs.impl.PsiAnnotationStubImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1  Build #IU-201.6668.121 
2020-04-09 08:49:53,690 [1843361]  ERROR - ubs.impl.PsiAnnotationStubImpl - JDK: 11.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2020-04-09 08:49:53,690 [1843361]  ERROR - ubs.impl.PsiAnnotationStubImpl - OS: Linux 
2020-04-09 08:49:53,690 [1843361]  ERROR - ubs.impl.PsiAnnotationStubImpl - Last Action: ChooseRunConfiguration
```

This happens when i try to debug my application and some fields have an error value like:

[image: intellij-error]

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

## Edit:

Installed over snap. Maybe i should install it manually to prevent the snap-auto-update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After disabling

`Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Data Views -> Java -> Enable alternative view for Collections classes`

i am able to debug the nested collections. <strike>I think this is still a workaround and should be fixed by JetBrains</strike>.

## Edit:

The approach above works, but at this point it looks like a Java Decompiler plugin does not work correctly. Thus no intellij bug.